# Flex box issue - Center Element truncated on overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overlay, center

I'm using some flex box attributes to place a simple div to the center of the screen :

```
//CSS

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

div {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

//HTML

<div></div>
```

It's working perfect but when I reduce the height of my screen to a size smaller than my div (smaller than 500px), I end up with a weird truncation : I can scroll down and see the bottom border but for some reason when I scroll up I can't reach the top border, it's hidden.

Am I missing something ? Anyone knows how to fix this ? 
I created a codepen to demonstrate the issue : https://codepen.io/stepinsight/full/MqmEME

Thanks heaps for your help !

Comment: Do you have a property on another class/element that says: overflow: hidden

Comment: Nope, just the code above ;)

Comment: not 100% sure but could have to do with your justify-content tag

Comment: Hi, Try `html, body{min-height:100%;}` instead of `html, body{height:100%;}`

Comment: Gosh ! Awesome ! It works perfect, thanks a million !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead `align-items:center;` you can use `margin:auto` on the flex child to center it :

```css
html {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 display: flex; 
 justify-content: center;
}

div {
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
 background-color: red;
 border: 5px solid black;
 margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[fork of your pen](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GXmOLW)
**Note:** `justify-content` is also removed on the codepen, when `margin:auto;` for a `flex` child works for both axis. `flex-shrink:0;` is also added so the container do not horizontaly shrinks (and also hides the left border) while the screeen becomes smaller in its width too.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works perfect ! Can't believe I didn't know about the margin:auto working for both axes :D You made my day !